# Datumbox Example code jar execution : Exception URI is not hierarchical at java.io.File. while running from datumbox

Tags: java, exception, machine-learning, jar, datumbox

I cloned the datum-box examples https://github.com/datumbox/datumbox-framework-examples  and wanted to run an example from the Terminal(working fine in Eclipse) but, getting exception while running the code from terminal.

ERROR :

```
INFO c.d.f.c.d.Dataframe$Builder - Dataset Parsing negative class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
at java.io.File.(File.java:418)
at com.datumbox.framework.common.dataobjects.Dataframe$Builder.parseTextFiles(Dataframe.java:93)
at com.datumbox.framework.applications.nlp.TextClassifier.fit(TextClassifier.java:143)
at com.datumbox.examples.TextClassification.main(TextClassification.java:99)
```